# CSS image animation crossfade loop - how do I make one image delay its fading animation (stay on page) longer than the others?

Tags: html, css, image, css-animations, cross-fade

I'm trying to create an affect where the initial image is displayed longer than the subsequently animated
images.  I'd like the first item to appear for 10 seconds and the others to display for 6.  I tried tweaking the timings, forcing an opacity for the first image, and noting seems to quite work.  I feel like I'm missing something crucial about how this works.

I think I get how the following images get their timing of 6 seconds, but what is determining the animation timing of the first one?  Can I just tell it to wait 4 seconds before it begins the loop so the first image rests on the page longer?

```css
.plattxt,
.goldtxt,
.coptxt {
  color: #6b6052;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 86%;
  margin-top: 93px;
  top: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.items {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px solid #f6921e;
  min-height: 120px
}

.item .img-thumbnail {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  max-height: 85px;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 230px;
  position: absolute;
}

.items h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #6b6052;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#crossfade>.fadecont {
  display: block;
  color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
}

#crossfade>.fadecont:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

#crossfade>.fadecont:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

#crossfade>.fadecont:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  -o-animation-delay: 18s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

#crossfade>.fadecont:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
  animation-delay: 24s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 " style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><i>Thank You to Our<br>2021 Sponsors!</i></h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="item" id="crossfade">
          <div class="fadecont">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#" />
            <span class="plattxt">Platinum</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fadecont">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#" />
            <span class="goldtxt">Gold</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fadecont">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#" />
            <span class="goldtxt">Gold</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fadecont">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#" />
            <span class="goldtxt">Gold</span>
          </div>
          <div class="fadecont">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="#" />
            <span class="coptxt">Copper</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“but what is determining the animation timing of the first one?”_ - `animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;`, the animation delay is `0s` here.

Comment: _“I think I get how the following images get their timing of 6 seconds”_ - these delays in multiples of 6 seconds delay starting of the animations accordingly. So if you want the animation of the second item to start after 10 seconds, and not 6 … then you need to set the delay accordingly. And carry that on for all the following ones, the next image’s animation delay would have to be `16s` instead of `12s`, etc.

Comment: @CBroe so when I adjust the timings as you suggest the first one stays on the page longer but it also seems like there's a gap between the first image and second image.

I have it like this:
animation: imageAnimation 42s linear infinite 0s;
Delays: 12/18/24/30/36

Any idea what I'm doing wrong there to cause that 1-2 second delay from image one fading out and image 2 appearing?